# unable to IMPORTXML stats from a form to Google Sheets - imported content is empty error

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to ImportXML data to my google sheet from this site:

```
https://pick224.com/
```

I used the copy Xpath option to get the 'xpath_query' but that didn't work.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://pick224.com/","/*[@id='DataRow31623_e9a5c9026c6106']/td[11]")
```

Later I also tried the copy full Xpath option but that also didn't work, I get the same #N/A error.

[Here is the specific element I want to grab from the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrQTF.png)

Is there anything preventing me from collecting data from this site or am I just not doing it properly?

I've been trying to solve this in the last few days, so I'd be grateful for any kind of help.
Here is my google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17i5Q5_8c_LqY7S361TPI4NRZZUOdlJ_0aa3vWiVGd7c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is that `id`dynamic?

Comment: I believe it isn't, because each row belongs to one unique player. In 'DataRow31623_e9a5c9026c6106' the '31623' identifies the player.

Comment: Could you try using `XPath Finder` extension? It gives the full path.

Comment: I already tried to paste in the full path but that didn't work: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[11]

Comment: Observing the source code I found [this url](https://c0dcn566.caspio.com/dp/9b0d7000447c1af4abb545f3b8ae) is called by the javascript. Can you query this url? However, in your case the url might be different. Especially the last part i.e `9b0d7000447c1af4abb545f3b8ae` . Change accordingly and try it once please and tell your results :)

Comment: No luck with that URL - I got the same error. That part "9b0d7000447c1af4abb545f3b8ae" does not change, that URL seems to be static.

Comment: I found this 'form#caspioform' element, can it be that the data is being pulled from a form and then put into a table? Would that be why it's not fully suitable for this IMPORTXML function?

Comment: Maybe we can try to `curl` the form with input values.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest how to do that or provide steps to process that?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. You can read basics of Curl in the official website, however our particular concern i.e submitting input values through curl is highlighted here in [this article](https://www.h3manth.com/content/methods-submit-form-post-using-curl-perl-python-ruby-lynx) . Also curl is available in most OSs by default and also online, for eg: [Online Curl](https://onlinecurl.com) . You must be wondering how `curl` could help you! Well if we can successfully curl the site to get the results, we can replicate the process in `Google Apps Script` and scrape the values.

Comment: Continued from previous comment: That value or any other values can be set in the spreadsheet. `ImportXML` isn't very powerful. We need to use a language of our choice here.

Comment: I'd like to automate and use the simplest solution available. I'm not familiar with CURL so if possible I'd like to use a different solution.

Comment: It's tougher than I imagined brother. I tried capturing HTTP requests using a tool called `HTTP debugger`. Mimicking the same HTTP requests using `curl` is something beyond my present knowledge. As of now I don't know simple methods to do the task. But hopefully someone answers here. Sorry, I tried my best ☹️

Comment: No problem, I appreciate that you tried to help. The ImportXML function works on other sites but the way the table is implemented on this sites seems to be making things worse  I hope someone can help me out with this pickle

Comment: Can you check [this tool](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/documentation/) called ImportFromWeb? I haven't tested it but they claim it works for javascript loaded websites.

Answer (score 0):

The url for downloading the whole .csv data seems fixed (`appsession` part is not needed).

```
https://c0dcn566.caspio.com/dp/9b0d7000447c1af4abb545f3b8ae?RecordID=&PageID=2&PrevPageID=&cpipage=3&download=1&CPIorderBy=P1GP&CPISortType=desc&downloadFormat=csv
```

However, you can't import it directly with an `IMPORTDATA` step since the file is too large. So you'll have to write a GoogleAppScript.

If you think the url of the .csv file could change, you can use [IMPORTFROMWEB](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) with javascript rendering activated to retrieve the address. The addon is not entirely free. Check the limit of the free plan.

[image: Hockey]

A1 : website of interest; A2 : XPath expression; A3:B3 : options to activate javascript (TRUE)

Formula in A4 (Concat+Regex):

```
="https://c0dcn566.caspio.com/dp/"&REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTFROMWEB(A1;A2;A3:B3);"""appKey"":""(.+?)""")&"?RecordID=&PageID=2&PrevPageID=&cpipage=3&download=1&CPIorderBy=P1GP&CPISortType=desc&downloadFormat=csv"
```

This way, you always have the last updated url for downloading the .csv.

You could also use `IMPORTFROMWEB` to retrieve the data but for the 1st page only (100 resuts). Incrementing the `cpipage` parameter in the url is not enough to load and fetch the rest of the data in GoogleSheets. Example with the first 5 columns :

[image: ImpWeb]

The GoogleAppScript part. In script editor, you can now use this kind of script ([source](https://www.labnol.org/code/20279-import-csv-into-google-spreadsheet)) :

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {

      // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
      //var csvUrl = "https://c0dcn566.caspio.com/dp/9b0d7000447c1af4abb545f3b8ae?RecordID=&PageID=2&PrevPageID=&cpipage=3&download=1&CPIorderBy=P1GP&CPISortType=desc&downloadFormat=csv";
      var csvUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 1).getValue();
      var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    }
```

You can declare directly the `csvUrl` variable with the fixed url of the csv. Or with the url you've build with `IMPORTFROMWEB`. In that case, you'll have to specify the position of the cell which contains the address (line 4, column 1 in the example).

Once you run the script, the active sheet will be populated with data. Warning : it could stress your CPU. When the data is loaded, you can create a new sheet and use `QUERY`, `FILTER`, `SORT`,... to transform the table previoulsy created.
If you want something automatic (script launched without your intervention), you should probably use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Alternatively, you could also write a custom function to load the csv. But it's a bit more tricky since you need to filter the data before importing it. Otherwise you'll get a "too large" error. For example, to keep only the players of the "AHL" league, you can write something like this (credits to [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256904/9978746) for the base script) :

```
function importCSV(url) {
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var x = 'AHL';
  var d=0;
 for(var i=0;(i-d)<csvData.length;i++) {
    if(csvData[i-d][0]!==x) {
      csvData.splice(i-d++,1);
    }
  }
  return csvData;
 }
```

So now, you can use the "importCSV" formula (importCSV(url.retrieved.with.IMPORTFROMWEB or fixed.url)) to load the data :

[image: Formula]

That's it for now.

Comment: Good to see you solved this :) how did you figure out that part: the url parameters? Earlier I was seeing only plain POST requests in dev tools. @E.Wiest

Comment: Hi. As you probably figured out, the parameters comes from the "Download Data" link located on the left of the page. Another option to load (move to next page)/filter the data (select specific items) could indeed be to emulate the  POST requests with a GoogleAppScript.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I was ignoring it the whole time. @E.Wiest